# how to inject keystrokes in a program like Safari from a bash script?

Tags: bash, shell-script, osx

I am trying to automate some keypresses every few minutes. The exact timing is still undetermined. But basically I want to capture a live chat dialogue. I'm sure I could do this more elegantly. I don't know much if anything about html or javascript or php etc.. I know a little bit of Bash and a little bit of AppleScript.

```
osascript -e 'tell app "Safari" to activate'
osascript -e 'set Script to "keystroke \"a\" using command down"'
osascript -e do Script
```

This would keep going and activate TextEdit and paste into there. But I haven't gotten past this point. This results in: **syntax error: Can’t set script to "keystroke \"a\" using command down". Access not allowed. (-10003)**

Changing `Script` to `myScript` and I get: **keystroke "a" using command down**.

But both methods still result in: **execution error: The variable do is not defined. (-2753)**

The fact that it calls **"do"** a variable makes my head spin.

I thought about using the `expect` program. I know I can run `expect` and say something like `send \n` to get a new line. However, that's about all I know. And I cannot find much documentation on how to send modifier keys like **Cmd-A**. It doesn't really matter whether `expect` or `osascript` as long as  the end result works.

I would like to somehow get away from the **select all** step because it selects the entire webpage to be copied instead of just the chat box. Any help would be appreciated very much.

Comment: I don't think this is technically off-topic here, but you'll likely get better responses on OSX tools on [Ask Different](http://apple.stackexchange.com/). :-)

Comment: Why don't you run the command directly, instead of setting it as a variable and calling it?

Comment: As the other commenter mentioned, you'll probably get better responses on Ask Different, the SE site for Apple stuff. But one specific tip: try the "Automator" tool that comes with OS X. It allows you to *record* events into a script.

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead:

```
osascript -e 'tell Application "Safari" to activate'
osascript -e 'tell application "System Events"' -e 'keystroke "a" using command down' -e 'end tell'
```